# Probability regarding die faces

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> **Problem:**
> Six faces of a cube are numbered randomly 1,2,3,4,5,6. The probability that faces 1 & 6, 6 & 3 and 3 & 1 will share an edge is:

I guess the other way of asking this problem is "probability that faces 1, 6 and 3 will share a corner" and then it will be simply: $$ \frac{^3P_3}{^6P_3} = \frac{1}{20} $$

(Here, $^nP_r$ denotes permutations of $r$ things from $n$ total things)

But, I was wrong. Any hints?

---

The correct answer was:

> $\dfrac{2}{5}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability you calculated was the probability that they all share a *specific* corner.  How many corners are there to check?  Is there overlap between any of the positive outcomes?

> $8\times \dfrac{1}{20}=\dfrac{2}{5}$

Comment: I guess I got caught in _"...share an edge..."_. Anyways, your answer clears the problem. Thanks

Comment: @JMoravitz Looking at a net: I chose 1 box out of 6 and then 1 box out of 4 adjacent(to the earlier) boxes and then again one box out of two adjacent to the 2nd chosen box. $P=\frac{\binom61 \binom41\binom21 }{\binom63 \times3!}=\frac25 $ Is this also right?

Answer (score 3):

Focusing on "sharing an edge" you can solve it like this.

If number 1 has been placed then $4$ of the $5$ remaining faces share an edge with the face that carries number 1. So if secondly number 6 is placed then the probability on sharing an edge with  number 1 equals $\frac45$.

After that $2$ of the remaining $4$ faces share an edge with 1 and 6.

so the probability equals $$\frac45\frac24=\frac25$$