# Adjacent numbers on a die

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Q. Six faces of a cube are numbered randomly $1,2,3,4,5,6$. The probability that faces $1$ & $6$, $6$ & $3$ and $3$ & $1$ will share an edge is __.

**My approach**: Total ways to write the $6$ numbers on the die $= 6!=720$.

Now, there are $6$ ways to write '$1$'. For each of those $6$ ways, there are $4$ ways to write '$3$' adjacent to '$1$'. And for each of these $6 \times 4$ ways, there are $2$ ways to write '$6$' adjacent to both, '$3$' and '$1$'. So, total favourable ways are $24\times2=48$. Thus, probability $= \dfrac{48}{720} = \dfrac{1}{15}$.

If the correct answer according to the link attached below is $\dfrac25$ please correct me where I am wrong.

[Probability regarding die faces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579706/probability-regarding-die-faces)

Comment: "Total ways to write the $6$
 numbers on the die $=6!=720$
.", are you sure ? Did you think overcounting ?

Comment: You should look at Brunsides' lemma to get rid of overcounting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start correctly. You have 48 ways to place 1,3 and 6.

For each of them, there are 6 ways to place 2,4 and 5 so you need to multiply this by 6.

I spent a long time to detect the error (more than 3 minutes!). The other process (4/5 * 2/4) seems more intuitive. And the risk to forget something is less.

Comment: this answer is wrong and misleading

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish All three approaches are valid. The $6!$ numberings of an oriented cube have $30$ equivalence classes under the $24$ orientation-preserving rotations of the cube. The ratios of any event which doesn't depend on orientation will always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), there are $30$ ways to construct six side dice using six different numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that $$\frac{6!+0+..+0}{24}=30$$

Understanding the lemma is given as homework to reader :)

Now, if these three numbers $1,3,6$ have common sides according to each other, there are $2$ ways to arrange these number on dice.Then, the other three numbers $2,4,5$ can be arranged by $3!$ ways as to any given arrangement of $1,3,6$ with given restriction.Then $$\frac{2 \times 3!}{30}=\frac{12}{30}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: We can consider a die, with 6 colors (one for each side). On This die, we have 720 way to put the 6 numbers, and previous results are correct. We can also consider that the die is unicolor, and we can say that we have only 30 ways to put the 6 numbers. Both reasoning are correct.